# How to parse a ISO 8601 String to Java Date on Android

Tags: java, android, date

I'm creating an app on Android which communicates with a server. That server gives me back a [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date String, like the following:

`2014-11-21 12:24:56.662061-02`

Then I'm trying to use Java's SimpleDateFormatter to parse my String, like this:

```
        Locale l = new Locale("pt","BR");
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ",l).parse(str_date);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
```

Thing is, this solution works partially. I'm able to get the year, month, day and hour correctly, but when it comes down to hours, minutes and seconds I always get the minutes wrong. If I try to print it using my example String, I get something like "12:35" instead of "12:24". I've tried different masks, using a Locale, not using a Locale, and nothing seems to work for me.

I've seen on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) that The SimpleDateFormatter doesn't support ISO 8601 very well, and that guy gave a solution using javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime() method, but the DatatypeConverter is not present on the Android SDK. So... What can I do to parse this String correctly?

Comment: There's a 'T' missing for your example to really be ISO 8601... But your format seems to handle this. The examples for `SimpleDateFormat` uses only a single ´Z´ character, maybe that's the problem? Also, you have too many ´S´s... There's never more than 3 digits so 'SSS' should do.

Comment: Well, I've tried many different masks, and the one using the triple S threw an exception. I also tried to use a single Z and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`S` is for milliseconds; 662061 is 662 s = 11 minutes.

Somehow throw away the microseconds, and use SSS.

```
str_date = str_date.replaceFirst("(\\d\\d[\\.,]\\d{3})\\d+", "$1");
```

Comment: It worked! I've used your code and changed the mask to "SSSZ" and it worked! Thank you very much!